# Sharepoint custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, choice-field, email-notification

I have a choice column. In that column, I have one entry that is called, CPIB Mtg. Space.

What I would like to do is when this choice is selected, an alert (email ) will go out to stakeholders that this choice was selected and they will then take the appropriate action.

I know about the "alert me" function, but that will only send an alert if anything changes.  I am more interested in one change only.  Am I gonna have to resort to a workflow? I would rather not.

Please advise you experts!

Comment: Why can't you use Workflow (It's straightforward with SharePoint Designer)? Can you deploy to server (you could use event receiver)?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Online? Try Flow. Very easy to write and do what you're after. It can trigger when an item updates, you can test to see if the field in question has changed, and you can send an email. All with no code.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**.

If you want to send an email notification for specific modification then you have to use workflow.

You can add a workflow on list, check for specific conditions on choice field and send email notification. Else end the workflow.

One Benefit of using workflow is you can customize the email template according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you want to achieve that send an email only when a choice column is changed.

Refer to the following article about send email when specific field changes in SharePoint:

http://officepowerups.com/2013/07/09/send-email-when-specific-field-changes-in-sharepoint/